# Model relationship based on compound key

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have two entities in an EF Core project: Store and Employee

Employee has a key that references Store, and also has an active flag.

When I pull back Stores from the DbContext, I want to see only those Employees that have the key that references the store in question and has an active flag.

I am stuck as to how to restrict based on the active flag.

The Minimal example looks like:

```
public class Employee
{
      public Guid Id {get; set;}
      [ForeignKey("Store")]
      public Guid StoreId{ get; set; }
      public bool IsActive {get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
      public Guid Id {get; set;
      public List<Employee> Employees{get; set;}
}
```

How can I generate the behavior I want?  At the moment, this will pull back every Employee, whether active or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a [Global Query Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

Simply add the following to your `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasQueryFilter(e => e.IsActive);
```

Unfortunately EF Core does not support query level filters. All you can do is to [Disable Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#disabling-filters). So if you want this to be per specific query or want to query for `Active == false`, I'm afraid you have to use projection as suggested in another answer.

Comment: This is a lot closer to what I need, but I still need to be able to look at inactive employees in other queries, just never in context of Stores.  Can you apply a query filter to a relationship?

Comment: Unfortunately no. All you can do is to disable the filters for specific query using `IgnoreQueryFilters()`.

Comment: You can have an additional entity with table splitting. One can have this query filter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    using( MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext()){
        var activeEmployees = (from em in db.Employees
                              join s in db.Store on em.StoreId == s.Id
                              where em.IsActive == true
                              select em).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Query is correct, but is there a way of defining this relationship (though the DBContext or model annotations) so that we don't need to use a query every time the data is retrieved?  We do not want inactive records by store

Comment: Not sure about that, but couldn't you run the query once and then use those records only?

Comment: We absolutely *could* but there should be a cleaner way of doing it.